# Mongodb Cast error: Part of the url is sent to _id. How to get the id from the request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have been searching on google and StackOverflow and this error has been around for quite a while but none of the proposed solutions was fit to my problem.

I have an endpoint

```
router.get('/posts/me', authController.isLoggedIn, catchErrors(blogController.myPosts))
```

to check which posts this user has

on the controller I have:

```
exports.myPosts = async (req, res) => {

    const posts = await Post.findById({author: {$eq: req.user._id}})

    res.json({'response':posts.length > 0 ? posts : 'You have no blog posts ☹️ ',
              'status':200})

}
```

Mongo returns a weird error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: 'me' }" at path "_id" for model "Post"
```

where 'me' is the last part of the URL. If I change, this part of the error changes as well.

I don't want to find posts by Id, I need to find all the posts where the author id is equal to the req.user_.id

The $where the operator is not valid on my atlas tier and I read that it isn't really efficient. The thing though is How can I overcome that error
and get a list of all the posts a user has created?

The complete error message:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _id: 'me' }" at path "_id" for model "Post"
    at new CastError (F:\test\Projects\test\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:29:11)
    at ObjectId.cast (F:\test\Projects\test\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:244:11)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (F:\test\Projects\test\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:948:12)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (F:\test\Projects\test\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1362:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (F:\test\Projects\test\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1352:15)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (F:\test\Projects\test\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1331:15)
    at cast (F:\test\Projects\test\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:252:34)
    at model.Query.Query.cast (F:\test\Projects\test\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4607:12)
    at model.Query.Query._castConditions (F:\test\Projects\test\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1790:10)
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (F:\test\Projects\test\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2045:8)
    at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOne] (F:\test\Projects\test\Backend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:16:8)
    at process.nextTick (F:\test\Projects\test\Backend\node_modules\kareem\index.js:369:33)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

I am using passport.js to handle the auth

```
exports.isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) =>{
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    res.status(401).json({'online':false, 
              'message':'Oops you must be logged in to do that ', 
              'status':401})
 }
```

To explain better what I am doing...
My index.js file has all my routes, I want to call a route using a get request that will (if the user is logged in) call a method that will query the db searching for all the posts that this user has published.
The url is fixed and I am not using it on the db query.
I get for the query the value of the user id that is on the req.

If I pass the id on the url and query the db using it, the error is gone but the db returns always null.

When I get all posts (using another route) I get this response:

```
 "response": [
        {
        "text": [
            "We still need to update this"
        ],
        "tags": [],
        "images": [],
        "_id": "5d4c1c0266afb7629c2513b9",
        "title": "Second Post",
        "description": "This is the second post for our platform",
        "author": "5d4923257b914233b834a7fb",
        "created": "2019-08-08T12:56:34.720Z",
        "slug": "second-post",
        "id": "5d4c1c0266afb7629c2513b9"
      }
```

The focus is on the author id:5d4923257b914233b834a7fb

If I change my endpoint to use the id from the url

```
 router.get('/posts/:id', authController.isLoggedIn, catchErrors(blogController.myPosts))

const posts = await Post.find({author: {$eq: req.params.id}})
```

The response is null, the error is gone but mongo returns null.

Comment: If my method is completely empty and just returning res.json(req.user) the error still persists.

Comment: I would use find() instead of findById(), find() returns a collection, findById() returns only one item.

Comment: I get the same error with find. Actually, If my method is empty, I get the same error. What I dont understand.

Comment: Is the error the same CastError?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same. I believe its something else now because the error happens even if the route does not exist.

Comment: How does your mongoose Post schema look like?, I assume, the problem is there.

Comment: I have 6 other methods on the blogController and they create posts, delete and update posts, return all the saved posts, posts by id... 
I am really confused how can that be a schema problema

Comment: I didn't know that part.. it was a rough guess only, I saw the cast error before when the schema id was not well defined.

Comment: I saw a solution somewhere where they say that including _id:String solves a similar problem. In my case I get no errors but nothing else that request Posts information works. This is really mind blowing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As weird as it might be, changing the kind of the request solved the problem.

```
router.post('/posts/me', authController.isLoggedIn, catchErrors(blogController.myPosts))
```

Even not sending any kind of data on the request, everything works as it is declared on my function.

Honestly, I don't understand why but as this solves my problem, I will stick with it.

Answer (score 2):

The error is that you're passing a string, in this case `me`, instead of a MongoDB ObjectID.

I guess the reason why this route doesn't work while others do is that the others are something like this: `/posts/:post_id`. Your code assumes in this `/posts/me` route that `me` is the post ID and tries to find the post with ObjectID `me` which obviously will crash.

If you paste the contents of index.js I'll be able to pinpoint the problem.

As for not getting results when you're using the id from the request parameter, get rid of the `eq` operand and call the route with a user id

```
await Post.find({ author: req.params.id })
```

Comment: This works everywhere, but on this method I posted the error. I can query users, posts, create users, login, logout, delete posts by id, update posts by id, findpost by id... just this one that doesnt work. Its quite weird tbh

Comment: "If my method is completely empty and just returning res.json(req.user) the error still persists"

I don't think the error comes from `blogController.myPosts`. Can you post your passport.js implementation that is called on `req.isAuthenticated()`

Comment: Edited my answer. Look for the place where `me` is getting picked up as `req.params.post_id`, or something like that, and then you try query for a post. Probably it starts in the file where your routes are defined

Comment: This error is just because of passing string "me" in the route which should be the objectID.

Comment: the weird thing is... I am not using req.params and me isnt a variable on the route.
The router.get() is just that line above and the method I am calling uses the req.user._id to query for the posts that have that id as authors.

Comment: I dont want to pass the user id on the url because it is already on the session. I just want to create a normal endpoint that will call myPosts method.
The method searchs for Posts that have the author with that Id in the req.user._id

Comment: Judging by the error the request probably goes through more middleware than what you've mentioned above. There's probably a route that catches `router.all('/posts/*', ...)` or something else. Without knowing the full contexts of index.js I can't know for sure.

As for not getting results when you're using the id from the request parameter, get rid of the `eq` operand: `await Post.find({ author: req.params.id })` and call the route with a user id

Comment: I solved the problem but I will test your solution as well. If removing the $eq parameter solves the error, I will accept your answer and not mine. I am more inclined to accept other's peoples answer than mine.
But thanks for taking time to help me out. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is also solved by changing the order of the router. If you have before this route, then something like this in the url '/posts/:id' and then perhaps '/posts/my' will no longer be the same as the match of the route with the one where there is an id.